# Python ASPX Javascript web scrape

Tags: javascript, python, asp.net, web-scraping

I am having a bit of a problem trying to web scrape the following website:

http://apps.fas.usda.gov/psdonline/psdquery.aspx

The problem is that it is a combination of frames, aspx and javascript.

I have attempted to use various example on stackoverflow as a handrail but can't get it to work. I have this so far which at least print out the right frame for the form.

```
import mechanize

url = 'http://apps.fas.usda.gov/psdonline/psdQueryFrameDisplay.aspx'
# url = 'http://apps.fas.usda.gov/psdonline/psdResult.aspx'

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
br.open(url)

response = br.response().read()

print response
```

I need to enter different values but for a starting point, 'wheat', 'production', ' all countries', '2013'

then click run query.

This produces a long webpage that I then want to parse into a dataframe. This last step is relatively straight forward if I can navigate the aspx and JS to get here.

Comment: you definitely need to plug in Selenium to interact with JS and frames.

Comment: any examples for this case?

Comment: see my [post](http://scraping.pro/recaptcha-solve-selenium-python/) where I use python + Selenium.